# Centos8/RHEL8 - How to dnf install package with missing dependencies?

Tags: dnf, cpan

Centos8, Trying to install mimedefang

```
dnf install mimedefang

- nothing provides perl(Digest::SHA1) needed by mimedefang-2.84-5.el8.x86_64
- nothing provides perl(IO::Stringy) >= 1.212 needed by mimedefang-2.84-5.el8.x86_64
```

The two dependencies do not exist in any repo that i know of. They are perl packages maintained at Meta::CPAN. I installed them using cpan instead of dnf.

```
cpan install Digest::SHA1
cpan install IO::Stringy
```

However dnf / rpm does not know this and still refuses to install mimedefang. I tried using `--skip-broken`, `--nobest` and `--best` and it still will not install.

For the love of god, how do you tell dnf to install anyways? Get dnf to acknowledge those two dependencies are installed, or ignore just those two dependencies? I don't want to tell dnf/rpm to ignore ALL dependencies as there are many others that need installing and are available in dnf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the files you installed via CPAN and enable the CentOS PowerTools repository:

```
   sudo dnf config-manager --set-enabled PowerTools
```

Then mimedefang will install without issues.

You might have a hard time installing those packages from PowerTools if you installed via CPAN, which is why you should **NEVER** install via CPAN unless you do it in an alternate directory (like /opt).  Let us know if you need help recovering a broken Perl install.

Comment: This worked, THANKS. To uninstall from CPAN i had to install "cpan install App::pmuninstall" and use that "pm-uninstall Digest::SHA1" to uninstall the packages.

Comment: This may be the right answer for Perl but does not answer the question title.